# I can't seem to catch this null error in form submission

Tags: javascript, velo

I have a Wix website with a form, Wix has something called an 'owner ID' which helps you recognize users by assigning a unique hashed name (this is all done automatically via Wix, e.g. assigning this ID to the user. e.g. "660ced7a-2c90-4955-ac15-8ca3a03ddd2c" However it appears that one of my users is somehow submitting data without an owner ID?
I don't understand how this can be possible I have tried forcing this situation to happen but I am unable to.

I even went as far as adding some page code to check if someone had a blank owner ID and disable the submit button and display a warning.

```
$w.onReady( function() {
if (wixUsers.currentUser.id === "" || wixUsers.currentUser.id == null || 
(wixUsers.currentUser.id).length < 5 ) {
    $w("#button1").hide()
    $w("#blank1").show()
 }
 } )
```

I am checking for `Null`, like blank or owner string less than length 5, despite having this in place it has somehow happened again today.

Does anyone have any ideas why it's happening or what I can do to stop it?

I thought about adding a data hook in to check the owner before submitting to the database, however I don't believe the hook can interact with page elements so all I could do is reject it or change it before entering.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's possible they're going through the dev tools. `hide` and `show` suggests that you're only changing the _visibility_ of the buttons, not adding/removing them from the DOM. If they're still visible in the DOM you can use them.

Comment: So if they're going through Dev tools then surely that means they're deliberately trying to bypass the validation?

Comment: It's what I would do. But I'm a terrible person without morals.

Comment: Hahaha! I will change the hide to disable, although I don't think this is a possibility as we're using the site as a portal to select members, only approved members have access to the form page, and as soon as you're an approved member you get the owner ID, so I really don't see how that part is being bypassed.

Comment: I'd just like to take this moment to remind you that front-end validation is for the user's convenience only. If your backend accepts unauthorized requests, it's only a matter of time before somebody tries it in Postman.

Comment: Okay maybe I will try the data hook, 'Before insert into DB if owner is null/blank/<5 then don't insert' - is that possible with a data hook as it needs the promise/item return in order to not kick out any errors, I tried nesting the 'return item' in an if statement and because I didn't return an item it ended up ignoring the datahook and inserting anyway

Comment: Stupidly enough after all of that I think it might be to do with database settings, 'Anyone can write to this table' was selected instead of 'Members only' - Sorry for wasting everyone's time!